# hiding an index of array laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to ask, how to hidden a name in role login.
So I have a output in laravel like this:

```
{
    "npp":"822345",
    "nama":"Handra Pratama",
    "bus_pergi":1,
    "bus_pulang":4,
    "hotel":null,
    "kamar":"K1",
    "teman_kamar":[
        {
            "nama":"Handra Pratama"
        },
        {
            "nama":"Louis Vernando"
        },
        {
            "nama":"Hallo Budi"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to hide role handra (because I'm login with handra username) in teman_kamar, and if i login role louis, i want to hide louis in `teman_kamar`, what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is in JS, so you can use a filter function in JS. But if you want to do it in PHP here is an example that I ran and it works per your case, because you always have the name that you want to hide under the first name key.

```
<?php 
$obj = [
    "npp" => "822345",
    "nama" => "Handra Pratama",
    "bus_pergi" => 1,
    "bus_pulang" => 4,
    "hotel" => null,
    "kamar" => "K1",
    "teman_kamar" => [
       [
          "nama" => "Handra Pratama"
       ],
       [
          "nama" => "Louis Vernando"
       ],
       [
        "nama" => "Hallo Budi"
       ]
    ]
];

$obj['teman_kamar'] = array_filter($obj['teman_kamar'], function($val) use ($obj) {
     return $val['nama'] !== $obj['nama'];
});
print_r($obj);
```